# Frontend get the result as soons as possible even with all the result is not ready yet

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am running a lot of fetch's (more than one hundred) in the backend. And the frontend has to wait the the backend run all those fetch until receive the whole result:

```js
    let result = []
    for (const origin of originList) {
      for (const destiny of destinationList) {

          const url = // mount url

          const respPromise = fetch(url)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then((data) => {
              result.push(data.text)
            })

          fetchPromises.push(respPromise)
      }
    }

    await Promise.all(fetchPromises)

    return result
```

The frontend (ReactJS) just does a fetch to call backend.

The code above receives the correct result after a long time because it has to wait dozens of fetchs to run. Is that a way so I can return each result as soon as it get ready?

Comment: Have you tried using an async generator?

Comment: @Vivick No. How is that?

Comment: You cannot `return` multiple times. So what do you actually want to do with each result? And judging from your code order does not matter?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting all results and then sending them at once, consider using a streaming approach where results are sent to the frontend as soon as they're available. You can use libraries like `stream` in the backend to create a readable stream that your frontend can consume but make sure to adapt the front-end as well.